# Reconciling outputs of jconsole and top

Tags: java, memory-management, jconsole

I am trying to look at memory management in Java. I have a program that creates a large collection (~500MB). I run `java` without any special arguments. Once this collection goes out of scope, I invoke the garbage collector using `System.gc()`. From jconsole, I can see that the heap memory in use is dramatically reduced. The same cannot be said of the RES output of the `top` linux command.

My only interpretation is that once the JVM gets hold of memory, it does not release it to the system as long as it is running. Is this correct?